# Regular expression to remove SMS unsupported characters

Tags: regex

I need to send SMS to the user, before send the message I want remove the unsupported characters from the message. I added my API documentation lines as the reference.

> Generally speaking, only a subset of the standard ASCII character set is supported for content being delivered to the user via SMS. The list of supported characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and the following:
>
> `@$_/.,"():;-=+*&%#!?<>'` plus space and newline `"\n"`.
>
> Most special characters are not supported and will cause messages to be rejected by the wireless operators. In particular, accented characters and the following are NOT supported:
>
> tab `[` `]` `~` `{` `}` `^` `|` `€` `\`
>
> When authoring content for delivery via SMS, it is also important to use the simple ASCII characters for the apostrophe, the ellipsis, and single and double quotes:
>
> use `'` instead of `<```>` and `<’>`
>
> use `"` instead of `<“>` and `<”>`
>
> use `...` instead of `…` (Note: that's three separate periods instead of the single ellipsis character)

So I'm looking for regular expression to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: What have you try first?

Comment: I don't have knowledge about regex, I didn't try anything yet.so i need help from experts.

Comment: you could, you know, try and learn a bit first before asking. http://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace all characters that don't match the valid ones:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9@$_\/.,"():;\-=+&%#!?<>' \n]
```

The `[]` means: "any of" and the `^` means: "not". So the whole expression says: Match anything but...

So you'd write:

```
replace all [^A-Za-z0-9@$_\/.,"():;\-=+&%#!?<>' \n] in the SMS by nothing
```

For further information (and your further questions ;-)) please have a look at this [Howto](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Hey Itchy, Thanks for the answer. It's useful. :)